# Finding the elements of all holes in an image using cvfindcontours without the usage of hierarchy

Tags: c++, opencv

I was wondering if there is a way to find the elements of all holes in an image using cvfindcontours without the usage of hierarchy? Because after researching, it seems that if I only want the holes without the external contour I would need to use hierarchy, so I was wondering if there is an alternative method?